# Error while trying to use ref inside useMemo()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to scroll FlatList to the certain index when screen is launched and data for the list is retrieved from the server.

I have a problem of using ref inside useMemo(). I'm getting an error:

> Cannot read property current of undefined.

How to fix this error? Does my approach correct?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 const WeeklyMeetings = props => {
        const [meetings, setMeetings] = useState(null)

        useEffect(() => {
          AllMeeting() // getting data from the server 
        }, []) 

      const getResult = useMemo(() => {
          flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: 15, animated: true })
      }, [meetings]);

      const flatListRef = useRef();


    const AllMeeting = async (id) => {
          setLoading(true)
          try {
           const meetings = await meeting.allMeetingsAsc(id)
           setMeetings(meetings)
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("error ", error)
          } 
        }

     return (
                <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
                    <FlatList
                        ref={flatListRef}
                        style={styles.list}
                        data={meetings}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        onScrollToIndexFailed={()=>{}}
                  />
                </View>
                )
    }
```

Comment: Give the ref an initial value, `const flatListRef = useRef(null);`

Comment: I just have tried that and got the same error.

Comment: What do you wish to do with getResult. Doesn't seem like useMemo returns any value in your case?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I don't want to do anything with getResult, I just want to useMemo() to scroll FlatList once data is retrieved from the server.

Comment: Well, you *are* trying to use it *before* it's defined in the function body. Also, that isn't quite what `useMemo` is designed to do, it just memoizes a value. Instead you likely just need an `useEffect` to do a side-effect like scrolling an element into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref needs to be defined before using it.

Also since you want to just scroll to index when you receive meeting value, you can make use of useEffect hook.

Also note that you only want to scrollToIndex once value meetings is available and hence you can skip the initial call to useEffect by keeping track of initialRender

```
const WeeklyMeetings = props => {
        const [meetings, setMeetings] = useState(null)

        useEffect(() => {
         const AllMeeting = async (id) => {
          setLoading(true)
          try {
           const meetings = await meeting.allMeetingsAsc(id)
           setMeetings(meetings)
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("error ", error)
          } 
        }
          AllMeeting();
        }, []) 


      const flatListRef = useRef();
      const initialRender = useRef(true)
      useEffect(() => { 
           if(!initialRender.current) {
                flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: 15, animated: true })
           } else {
                initialRender.current = false;
           }
     }, [meetings])



     return (
                <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
                    <FlatList
                        ref={flatListRef}
                        style={styles.list}
                        data={meetings}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
                           {length: 50, offset: 50 * index, index}
                         )}
                  />
                </View>
                )
    }
```

According to [`Documentation`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex)

> You would need to implement a getItemLayout function for FlatList
>   since scrollToIndex Cannot scroll to locations outside the render
>   window without specifying the getItemLayout prop.

Comment: I just have tried this code, when I'm opening the screen, it doesn't scroll anywhere, in the debugger initialRender always  {current: false}

Comment: initalRender is supposed to remain false post the initalRender. only when meetings value is updated `flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: 15, animated: true })` should be called

Comment: Correction: so initialRender is first true, then false, If to add console log inside if, it shows up, but it doesn't scroll FlatList.

Comment: Please implement getItemLayout function for FlatList since the index can be outside of render view. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex

Comment: It still doesn't scroll list on the screen opening even after implementing getItemLayout()

Comment: if wrap flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex with setTimeout it will work though